# Tabbar with Async Task in Android

Tags: android, tabs, android-asynctask, android-tabhost

I have built an application which starts to copy images and some data from application to internal memory once applications is running for the first time. Then use these data later on somewhere else in another activity.

Copying process takes more than 30 sec. so I wanted to do this in a async task. But I couldnt make it work. Async task runs well but I need to create tab specs and assign intents to each of spec on onPostExecute method. But all I see is tab bar without specs and nothing works.

so any idea how to built it in this way ?

Any help will be appreciated.
 Here my Activity is,

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tabbar_main);

    myJSON = new DataBaseJSONFunctions(this);

    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

    TabWidget tabWidget = tabHost.getTabWidget();

    Resources res = getResources();
    //TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

    TabHost.TabSpec spec;
    Intent intent;

    // Starting Initialization process.
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    if(!prefs.getBoolean("firstRun", false)) {

        initializeAll();
        // Set "firstRun" true to make it runs once application is installed.
        prefs.edit().putBoolean("firstRun", true).commit();
    }
```

And I wanna put this block in an async task,

```
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this,Activities.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("activities").setIndicator("act",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_activities_selector)).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    // doing the same things.
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Promotions.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("promotion").setIndicator("Promotion",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_promotions_selector)).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);


    // doing the same things for Albums Activity.
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this,Menu.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("menu").setIndicator("Menü",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_menu_selector)).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    for(int i = 0; i < tabWidget.getChildCount(); i++){
        tabWidget.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_bar);
    }

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
```

btw, Iam passing context of my activity to async task.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to populate `TabHost` from `AsyncTask` is a little bit unconventional. I would suggest to populate `TabHost` with tabs as soon as your application is started, then you run `AsyncTask`, which may or may not display `ProgressDialog` to let the user to know something is going on, and after your `AsyncTask` has finished, you may fill your UI with the new data.

Comment: I will try it as soon as possible, but the thing is If I populate the tabbar as soon as application starts how would I do it ?  I mean I need the data returned from AsyncTask to fill UI. If I start the intent without data I will get null pointer.

Comment: you may use the saved data from the previous run, or manually crafted placeholder data if this is your first run. The point is, your UI should display something, and then you may start background update and, probably, show `ProgressBar` to tell the user something is going on.